# Why doesn't "Navigation Item" show up in one of my ViewControllers in Interface Builder?

Tags: interface-builder, xcode6

I have some working navigation between ViewControllers, using a `UINavigationController`.

But if you look in the image, you'll see my ViewControllers in InterfaceBuilder have an item called "Navigation Item" which showed up when connecting it to the `UINavigationController`.

However, the `TutorialViewController` doesn't have this. How do I get it to show up? I tried copying the Navigation Item from one controller and pasting it into another, but that didn't work.

The really weird thing is that if I use the button on the front page to go to the Tutorial page, the navigation works, shows a back button and everything.

[image: Interface builder screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag & drop a `Navigation Item` from the object library onto your ViewController in InterfaceBuilder

Comment: So I'm confused about why my other views had them, and this one didn't. But that did the trick, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, this solves the issue but doesn't answer the question.